# gdb command to find arguments

Tags: assembly, gdb

Is there a gdb command to find the location of the arguments of a function? I am debugging a function fun1 that takes as input a string that I enter in stdin. However, I can't find the location where this string is stored. Should the first argument always be stored in $ebp+8?

Comment: `ebp` may be set up by the function prologue, it is however not mandatory. The first argument will be at `esp+4` upon entry to the function, but `esp` may be changed later.

Comment: @Jester: I'm still doing 32bit, but there at least the first argument, technically speaking, is at 8(%ebp) (or 8(%esp) if no prologue): argc; argv[0]; argv[1]. I assume you just mis-spoke and know that. To OP: note also that  locations above are actually pointers to the true location.

Comment: @gnometorule Not sure what you mean. The first arg is at `esp+4` at function entry, or at `ebp+8` after a `push ebp; mov ebp, esp` sequence. The additional offset of 4 comes from the `push` of course.

Comment: @Jester: he's talking about stdin. I took that as that he is actually talking about a main function taking command line arguments, and that he needed argv[1]. In a function call that is not main_, you're right.

Comment: But he specifically said `function fun1` and that's clearly not `main`. Not to mention you are wrong for `main` too, because `argv` has type `char**` so the layout is not `argc; argv[0]; argv[1]`, it's actually `argc; argv` and then you need to dereference `argv+4`.

Comment: @Jester: You're obviously right...:) I'll be in the corner over there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the location of a variable using "info address".  This will try to print the location in a user-friendly way.  If you know DWARF you can use "maint set dwarf2 always-disassemble 1" to have it dump the DWARF disassembly.